# Installation of Oracle Database 11g Express Edition on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu-12.10, database-administration, oracle-11g

I intalled the Oracle database have followed this steps [link|http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.in/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html?showComment=1357195285714#c4393074524447658792] .

1.Downloaded 11g express edition

2.Created a new user `oracle` under the group `dba`. Following steps are executed using this.

3.`unzip oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip` and then Converted the rpm to the Ubuntu package

```
sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

4.Created `/sbin/chkconfig` file and added the entries as specified here

5.Created `/etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf` and added the entries as specified in same link as above.

6.Below steps:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk
mkdir /var/lock/subsys
touch /var/lock/subsys/listener
```

7.`sudo dpkg --install oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb` (.deb generated in step 3)

8.`sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure` (left the default values as it is)

9.Set the following env variables in `~/.bashrc` file

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export ORACLE_SID=XE export NLS_LANG=$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

10.Below steps:

```
chown -R oracle:dba /var/tmp/.oracle
chmod -R 755 /var/tmp/.oracle
chown -R oracle:dba /tmp/.oracle
chmod -R 755 /tmp/.oracle
```

11.`sudo service oracle-xe start` Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.

12 . `sqlplus / as sysdba` and got the following

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Jan 3 09:41:58 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle. All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.
```

Now when exectute any SQL statements on SQLplus, i end up with the following error

```
SQL> select * from dual;
select * from dual
* ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available Process ID: 0 Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

I have increased the swap memory as specified in [here |http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.in/2011/09/installing-1-gb-swap-without.html]

```
free -m

total used free shared buffers cached
Mem: 3901 3428 473 0 182 1988 -/+ buffers/cache: 1258 2643 
Swap: 5066 0 5066
```

what the solution for this error ?

```
ORACLE not available Process ID: 0 Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

please help me.